# Nginx gives 404 error on specific pages only

Tags: server, nginx

My website hosted on ubuntu 16.04 and nginx/1.10.3
My problem is, that specific pages return 404, I am pretty sure the issue lies with nginx settings where I screwed up somehow.
Here is my website nginx config https://codeshare.io/GqbBXM

Obviously I don't see accessing this page as an error in logs (in either errors or access ones), but I do get a lot of other errors there like so

```
2020/04/06 04:42:47 [error] 24414#24414: *4022326 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.113.141.52, server: domainname.me, request: "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "memcached://[::1]:11213", host: "domainname.me", referrer: "https://domainname.me/series4"
2020/04/06 04:42:47 [error] 24414#24414: *4022326 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.113.141.52, server: domainname.me, request: "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8087/manifest.json", host: "domainname.me", referrer: "https://domainname.me/series4"
```

I don't know where to start with fixing this, please guide me through this process.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an ipv6 related issue. You can try to set memcached to use socket and change the address of the app from localhost to 127.0.0.1. It limits to ipv4.
Or set memcached and the app to work with ipv6.

Comment: If you are talking about changing this 
upstream memcached.anime {
  server localhost:11213;
  keepalive 100;
}
To this
upstream memcached.anime {
  server 127.0.0.1:11213;
  keepalive 100;
}
I actually tried that before posting my question here... it didn't help.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm talking about. Aparently your upstream destination is not listening ipv6. Tried to connect via socket? To avoid TCP issues?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? I am not exactly savvy in this

Comment: Sure! When you point to localhost, the hosts or DNS service can delivery the addresses pointed in two ways: an IPV4 address and a IPV6 address. Then, the client tries to connect to respective addresses. Assuming he tried first IPV6: When it receives an error, it tries IPV4, but the error keep logged. In another words, if it receives from DNS that localhost address ::1, it first going try to connect at ::1, using IPV6. But the upstream is not listening for IPV6. So, your server returns an error, and your client try to connect the other address it received, 127.0.0.1.

Comment: That said, I like to use unix connections between services running on the same machine, not TCP. When you upstream to localhost or 127.0.0.1, you are using tcp. But, when you point to a sock, beyond performance gains, you get rid of thos tcp issues. Here's a tutorial that should explain how to start: 

https://guides.wp-bullet.com/configure-memcached-to-use-unix-socket-speed-boost/

Comment: Fuh... this took awhile, you didn't undestand my question, I wanted to know what and how EXACTLY to change on my server to make it work...
I made nginx config like that 
upstream memcached.anime {
  server unix:/tmp/memcached.sock;
  keepalive 100;
}
Well it got rid of errors in nginx logs, but didn't fix initial issue with 404 page... I still have no idea where to look and what to do...

Comment: OMG! I haven't understood your problem allright! You are right! I'm so ashamed right now!! Gimme a sec, gonna read your config file again.

Comment: Need more information. Which page is the specific page that returns this error? Was your access log turned on at the time you tested? What was printed on it when the error ocurred?

Comment: don't worry about making a mistake, its more of an assumption.
The issue here is that there is NOTHING in both access & error logs. This is why I don't even know where to look for a reason.

Comment: But are your access logs turned on?  We can find clues about where the errors are coming from. You can start by replacing the name of one those error pages, on those error 400 mappings, to find out.

Comment: Yes, access logs turned on, BUT, there isn't a thing about accessing problem page... because it returnes 404 so it isn't even there..
How do I do mapping to find out the issue? Please tell me.